# Unable to install ros-iron-image-transport-plugins

Tags: installation, binary, binaries, ros-iron

I am trying to install the said package on my Ubuntu Jammy machine with ROS2 Iron already installed. I am able to source the iron environment properly without any errors (`source /opt/ros/iron/setup.bash`)

So, to install the said package, I first ran `sudo apt-get update` which gave the output:

```
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                          
Hit:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                             
Hit:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                            
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                  
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease   
Hit:8 https://packagecloud.io/sensu/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease     
Hit:9 http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

Then I tried installing the said package with the command: `sudo apt-get install -y ros-iron-image-transport-plugins` to which I got the below errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport ros-iron-compressed-image-transport ros-iron-theora-image-transport
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport ros-iron-compressed-image-transport ros-iron-image-transport-plugins ros-iron-theora-image-transport
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 660 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,529 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport amd64 3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.112549
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-compressed-image-transport amd64 3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.112554
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-theora-image-transport amd64 3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.110033
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-image-transport-plugins amd64 3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.114631
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport/ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport_3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.112549_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-compressed-image-transport/ros-iron-compressed-image-transport_3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.112554_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-theora-image-transport/ros-iron-theora-image-transport_3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.110033_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-image-transport-plugins/ros-iron-image-transport-plugins_3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.114631_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

So, as suggested in the last line of the above output, I ran `sudo apt-get install -y ros-iron-image-transport-plugins --fix-missing` & got the below output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport ros-iron-compressed-image-transport ros-iron-theora-image-transport
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport ros-iron-compressed-image-transport ros-iron-image-transport-plugins ros-iron-theora-image-transport
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 660 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,529 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport amd64 3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.112549
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-compressed-image-transport amd64 3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.112554
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-theora-image-transport amd64 3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.110033
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-image-transport-plugins amd64 3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.114631
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport/ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport_3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.112549_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-compressed-image-transport/ros-iron-compressed-image-transport_3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.112554_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-theora-image-transport/ros-iron-theora-image-transport_3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.110033_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-image-transport-plugins/ros-iron-image-transport-plugins_3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.114631_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap
```

Any idea how I can fix this problem? Please let me know if I should run any additional commands & paste the output.

I have been stuck with this problem for some days now

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions.